# Is there a way to use "Invoke Web Request" to open the Uri directly in a Chrome browser application?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, oauth-2.0

I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to simulate a Oauth authorization call, where my Uri ("https://oauthloginauthorizestring") would open up in Chrome browser for my user to submit my credentials and then I could make some http calls with my logged in user's Authorization token. I've gotten stuck on how to make the login prompt pop in Chrome browser, while still having visibility of the Response object and Response fields like headers. The first method I tried was using Invoke Web Request method to make a GET request on the login url, but the response is a "html" page with no "Forms" or other input mechanisms to input my credentials. I'm hoping to find a way to use Invoke-WebRequest but have it trigger the Uri popping up in a Chrome browser application. So far, the only way I've been able to make the login Uri pop up in Chrome, is using "Start Process" with the path of my Chrome program, but then I can't get any Response Headers and hence no redirection "Location".

I have a couple questions that I'm hoping someone on here can give me some guidance on. I'd greatly appreciate any advice you can give!

1. Is there a way to make the Invoke-WebRequest open the Uri in a browser like Chrome?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to gather the "Response" Headers from opening a Uri directly in a Chrome browser using Start-Process command?

Here is the Invoke-Web Request method I started out with, and the "Start-Process" method I'm working with now.

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://oauthloginauthorizestring" -MaximumRedirection 0 -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable 'Session'}
catch{}
```

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList '--user-data-dir=c:\temp', '--start-fullscreen','https://oauthloginauthorizestring' -PassThru`